# Lifting back homomorphisms from localized modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Refer to exercises 9, 10 of chapter 3 in Lang's algebra, page 167.

In particular, let $A$ be a commutative ring, $p$ a prime ideal and $M, N$ $A$-modules. Then $M_p, N_p$ are the localized $A_p$ modules. Let $f: M_p \rightarrow N_p$ be a homomorphism of $A_p$ modules. How can we lift this homomorphism to an  $A$-homomorphism $M \rightarrow N$ of the initial modules?

Comment: Dear Manos, if you refer to an exercise in Lang, you should copy it in your question and not force users to try to get hold of that book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are starting with a sequence of $A$-modules
$$
0 \to M' \stackrel f\to M \stackrel g\to M'' \to 0.
$$
You want to show that if for each prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$ the induced sequence of $A_\mathfrak{p}$-modules
$$
0 \to M'_\mathfrak{p} \stackrel{f_\mathfrak{p}}\longrightarrow M_\mathfrak{p} \stackrel{g_\mathfrak{p}}\longrightarrow M''_\mathfrak{p} \to 0
$$
is exact, then the original sequence is exact. Here the map $f_\mathfrak{p}$, for example, just sends $x/s$ to $f(x)/s$. You don't need to perform any sort of "lifting" on $f_\mathfrak{p}$, because you already have $f$. One way of solving the problem is to find ways to apply the fact that if $N_\mathfrak{p} = 0$ for all primes $\mathfrak{p}$, then $N = 0$. [You could try this with $N = \operatorname{Ker} f$. What is the relationship between $\operatorname{Ker} f$ and $\operatorname{Ker} f_\mathfrak{p}$?]

I should mention that if $M'$ is [finitely presented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_presented_module#Finitely_presented_module) then there is a relationship between $A$-linear $M' \to M$ and $S^{-1}A$-linear $S^{-1}M' \to S^{-1}M$. Proposition 2.10 of [Eisenbud's book](http://books.google.com/books/about/Commutative_algebra_with_a_view_toward_a.html?id=Fm_yPgZBucMC) shows that in this situation we have a natural isomorphism
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_{S^{-1}A}(S^{-1}M', S^{-1}M) \approx S^{-1}\operatorname{Hom}_A(M', M).
$$
So you might suggestively call Georges' example "the identity map divided by $2$".

Comment: What if i start with a sequence $0 \rightarrow M_{p,1} \rightarrow M_{p,2} \rightarrow M_{p,3} \rightarrow 0$? Can i get a sequence $M_1 \rightarrow M_2 \rightarrow M_3$? Note that at this point i only want to get the sequence, i am not worrying about exactness.

Comment: @Manos I've no idea (though I think it would be best to just talk about one homomorphism $M'_\mathfrak{p} \to M_\mathfrak{p}$ then, since that doesn't seem any easier/harder). I'm most worried about the case when, say, $M$ doesn't inject into $M_\mathfrak{p}$. So I'd like to play around with examples like that and try to think about the problem geometrically. But your best bet is probably Georges :)

Comment: Dear Manos, you have had two answers to your original question. If this does not satisfy you, I suggest you write another, precise question with quantificators in front of $p$. In particular the example in my post  shows that the  answer to your question above is "no" since if you cannot lift $0 \to M_p \to N_p \to 0$, you certainly cannot lift $0 \to M_p \to N_p \to 0_p \to 0$

Comment: @Dylan: thanks Dylan, you revealed the point that was confusing me: i already have $f$, no need to do any lifting.

Comment: Since no one has mentioned it, perhaps it is worth noting that the functor $M\rightarrow M_p$ is the tensor product $\otimes_A A_p$. So we know certain things about it on more-general principles...

Answer (score 4):

In general, given an $A_p$-linear morphism $f:M_p\to N_p$ it is impossible to find a morphism of $A$-modules $g: M\to N$ lifting $f$ in the sense that  $g_p=f.$

For example, let $A,M$ and $N$ all be equal to $\mathbb Z$. Choose for $p$    the zero ideal $p=(0)$.
Then $A_p=M_p=N_p=\mathbb Q$ and you can choose for $f:\mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$ the morphism $f(q)=\frac{q}{2}$.
The only  $\mathbb Z$-linear maps $g:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ are of the form $g(n)=an$ for some $a\in \mathbb Z$ and clearly none of them lifts $f$.

Comment: The issue is that the exercise 10b) says to prove that the sequence $0 \rightarrow M_1 \rightarrow M_2 \rightarrow M_3 \rightarrow 0$ is exact if and only if the sequence $0 \rightarrow M_{p,1} \rightarrow M_{p,2} \rightarrow M_{p,3} \rightarrow 0$ is exact. The forward direction is not a problem. The backward direction however requires some kind of lifting of the sequence to the initial modules.

Comment: @Manos: Take A=Z and p=0 as Georges suggests, then take M1 = 0, M2=Z/2Z, M3=0.  Then the original sequence is not exact, but it becomes exact after localizing at p (it becomes 0→0→0→0→0).  Presumably you need some extra hypotheses.

Comment: @Manos You really want to require that the second sequence is exact for all primes $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$.

Comment: @Dylan: you are right, this is it. However, the question of how to lift back the sequence still remains.

Comment: @Manos Oh, do you want conditions under which a map $M_\mathfrak{p} \to N_\mathfrak{p}$ comes from an $M \to N$? That seems interesting.

Comment: @Dylan: Precisely!